# Why this error shows up on mysql code when authentication?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = '1555496297', `user_data` = 'a:1:{s:17:\"flash:new:message' at line 1

Running on mySQL 4.0, PHP. 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you would share your query. It seems that this is a `syntax error`.
Chek your query `syntax` or `share your code` here.